# How to add progress bar inside dplyr chain in R

Tags: r, progress-bar, dplyr

I like dplyr's "progress_estimated" function but I can't figure out how to get a progress bar to work inside a dplyr chain. I've put a reproducible example with code at the bottom here.

I have a pretty big data.frame like this:

```
                cdatetime latitude longitude   
1 2013-01-11 06:40:00 CST 49.74697 -93.30951
2 2013-01-12 15:55:00 CST 49.74697 -93.30951 
3 2013-01-07 20:30:00 CST 49.74697 -93.30951
```

and I'd like to calculate sunrise times for each date, using the libraries

```
library(dplyr)
library(StreamMetabolism)
```

I can get dplyr's progress_estimated bar to work within a loop, e.g.:

**Ugly loop (works)**

```
p <- progress_estimated(nrow(test))

for (i in 1:nrow(test)){
  p$tick()$print()
  datetime = as.POSIXct(substr(test$cdatetime[i], 1, 20), tz = "CST6CDT")
  test$sunrise[i] <- sunrise.set(test$latitude[i], test$longitude[i], datetime, "CST6CDT", num.days = 1)[1,1]
}
```

but how can I nest it in my function, so I can avoid using a loop?

**Prefer to use:**

```
SunriseSet <- function(dataframe, timezone){
  dataframe %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(# calculate the date-time using the correct timezone
      datetime = as.POSIXct(substr(cdatetime, 1, 20), tz = timezone),
      # Get the time of sunrise and sunset on this day, at the county midpoint
      sunrise = sunrise.set(latitude, longitude, datetime, timezone, num.days = 1)[1,1])
}
```

***How to get a progress bar here?***

```
test2 <- SunriseSet(test, "CST6CDT")
```

Here's some example data:

```
test <- data.frame(cdatetime = rep("2013-01-11 06:40:00", 300),
                   latitude = seq(49.74697, 50.04695, 0.001),
                   longitude = seq(-93.30951, -93.27960, 0.0001))
```

Comment: I feel that the progress bar should be able to be used groupwise as well. For example, if you group date then mutate across each group.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rather than using `rowwise()`, perhaps try pairing the `map*` functions from `purrr` with `progress_estimated()`.  This answer follows the approach from https://rud.is/b/2017/03/27/all-in-on-r%E2%81%B4-progress-bars-on-first-post/.

First, wrap your function in another function that updates the progress bar:

```
SunriseSet <- function(lat, long, date, timezone, num.days, .pb = NULL) {
  if (.pb$i < .pb$n) .pb$tick()$print()
  sunrise.set(lat, long, date, timezone, num.days)
}
```

Then, iterate through your inputs with `pmap`, or `pmap_df` (to bind the outputs into a dataframe):

```
library(purrr)
pb <- progress_estimated(nrow(test), 0)
test2 <- test %>% 
  mutate(
    sunrise = pmap_df(
      list(
        lat = latitude, 
        long = longitude,
        date = as.character(cdatetime)
      ),
      SunriseSet,
      timezone = "CST6CDT", num.days = 1, .pb = pb
    )$sunrise
  )
```

Comment: That works! I'll see how I do adding the sunset to the output dataframe... thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I dont really like my solution but it works.

```
print_tick_function <- function(x, p) {
  p$tick()$print()
  data.frame(x)
}

SunriseSet <- function(dataframe, timezone){
  p <- progress_estimated(nrow(dataframe))
  dataframe %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    do(print_tick_function(.,p)) %>%
    mutate(
      datetime = as.POSIXct(substr(cdatetime, 1, 20), tz = timezone),
      sunrise = sunrise.set(latitude, longitude, datetime, timezone, num.days = 1)[1,1]
    )
}
test2 <- SunriseSet(test, "CST6CDT")
```

Comment: Thanks @nehiljain, I have a lot to learn about do(). I tried it on a larger data.frame and the progress bar isn't accurate - progress goes to 100%, but the function is still chugging through several minutes later.

Comment: @Nova I had the same experience, progress hits 100% way before the calculation finishes in practice