# How to add a progress bar in a dplyr group_by and summarize?

Tags: r, dplyr, progress-bar

Here is some code:

```
library(dplyr)
foo <- data.frame(a=runif(1000))
foo %>% group_by(a1=round(a, 1)) %>% summarize(num=n())
```

How can I get a progress bar on the `group_by` and/or `summarize`?

Note this example is simplified.  The progress bar is more useful when the group_by and summarize are more expensive, so I can tell if it's going to complete in one minute, one hour, one day, or worse.

I see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42725428/how-to-add-progress-bar-inside-dplyr-chain-in-r#45260952) that talks about using `rowwise`, but I don't want `rowwise`.  I see the deprecated [progress_estimated](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/progress_estimated.html), and the [progress package](https://github.com/r-lib/progress) it refers to, but it's not obvious to me how to modify the example above.

Comment: If you have a large `group_by(x) %>% summarize` that is running slowly, you might consider using other packages like `data.table` or `collapse` or `arrow` or `duckdb` that can perform those calculations much faster when there are (for instance) more than 10k groups. All of those packages have or include wrappers which let you leverage existing `dplyr` code with only minor additions. (For instance, the `dtplyr` package converts `dplyr` chains to use `data.table` for calculations.)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you have a mechanism to split up data and save each group results to disk when done then combined them once all group are done. Otherwise you risk losing the whole calculation progress due to unplanned accident that interupted R while everything is still in RAM.

Here is a sample solution to add progress bar with `group_split`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(progress)

set.seed(100)
sample_data <- tibble(groups = rep(letters[1:10], 20),
                      number = runif(200, min = 0, max = 100))

# a summary function to process for each group and update progress bar
summary_fn = function(group_df) {
  # add sleep to simulate long calculation otherwise it would finish in no time
  Sys.sleep(runif(1, min = 0, max = 5))
  pb$tick()
  group_df %>%
    mutate(number = number + 5)
}

# create progress bar
pb <- progress_bar$new(total = 10)

splitted_data <- sample_data %>%
  # split data into list of group that will be map to summary_fn
  group_split(groups) %>%
  # map_dfr will process each group separately and as summary_fn
  # update the progress bar for each run you will see the process
  map_dfr(.f = summary_fn)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Here is a blurry GIF of what progress bar look like when running above code.

[image]